# Return None Value object properties in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have two class A and B, try to change value of self variable with multiprocessing executing and return None value:

Class A:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def update_value(self, new_value):
        print('Value in class A : ', new_value)
        self.value = new_value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
```

Class B:

```
from A import A
import multiprocessing as mp

instance_1 = A()

instance_2 = A()


p1 = mp.Process(target=instance_1.update_value, args=[100])
p2 = mp.Process(target=instance_2.update_value, args=[200])

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

print('Value in class B', instance_1.value)

print('Value in class B', instance_2.value)
```

Result:

```
Value in class A :  100
Value in class A :  200
Value in class B None
Value in class B None
```

I Want to get same result in class A and B from value variable.
How can Do that?

Comment: Processes do not share the same memory space, so you cannot work on the same instance of a class. There are proper way to share data among processes (like Pipes, Queues and others). An alternative would be to use threads, but that depends on your specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Processes do not share the same memory space, so you cannot work on the same instance of a class. Instead you should use a [BaseManager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager) to have different processes work with the same instance of a class. You register your class to the base manager, the start it and define the class instances through the manager. Like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def update_value(self, new_value):
        print('Value in class A : ', new_value)
        self.value = new_value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

manager = BaseManager()
manager.register('A', A)
manager.start()
shared1 = manager.A()
shared2 = manager.A()


p1 = mp.Process(target=shared1.update_value, args=(100,))
p2 = mp.Process(target=shared2.update_value, args=(200,))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

print('Value in class B', shared1.get_value())
print('Value in class B', shared2.get_value())
```

Output:

```
Value in class A :  100
Value in class A :  200
Value in class B 100
Value in class B 200
```